# multiple click event with one function using javascript and jquery. This code is working fine but need some simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few buttons on my page and I have written click events for them. They are working fine but I am looking for a way to make a generic method.

```
$("#stopBtn1").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('videoControl1').pause();    
    document.getElementById('videoControl1').currentTime = 0;
});
$("#stopBtn2").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('videoControl2').pause();
    document.getElementById('videoControl2').currentTime = 0;
});
$("#stopBtn3").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('videoControl3').pause();
    document.getElementById('videoControl3').currentTime = 0;
});
```

Comment: Did you finish your question?  Not really sure what you're asking and will prompt downvotes until sorted.

Comment: you could have change selector to a class also

Comment: I guess he is trying to make a generic method

Comment: @Rush.2707 yes, as in the duplicate

Comment: Change Id to class. and use this jQuery -   $(".stopBtn").click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find('.videoContro').pause();
 $(this).parent().find('.videoControl').currentTime = 0;
});

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#stopBtn1, #stopBtn2, #stopBtn3").click(function() {
var idNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("stopBtn","");
  document.getElementById('videoControl' + idNumber).pause();
  document.getElementById('videoControl' + idNumber).currentTime = 0;
});
```

`idNumber` will represent the number in the elements `id`

Comment: No problem happy to help, if it solved your problem consider marking it as answered.

Comment: yes. i did it. once again thank you.